# `mod_deflate` is returning `Content-Encoding: gzip`. Is that normal?

Tags: apache-2.2, gzip, mod-deflate

`mod_deflate` is configured on my Apache 2.2 web server.  But my response headers are showing `gzip` as the `Content-Encoding` instead of `deflate`:

```
HTTP/1.1 200 OK
Date: Mon, 26 Sep 2011 22:26:11 GMT
Server: Apache
Last-Modified: Mon, 26 Sep 2011 11:32:54 GMT
Accept-Ranges: bytes
X-Powered-By: Servlet/2.5 JSP/2.1
Vary: Accept-Encoding,User-Agent
Content-Encoding: gzip
Age: 36
Content-Length: 144338
Keep-Alive: timeout=15
Connection: Keep-Alive
Content-Type: text/html; charset=UTF-8
```

Notice this line:

```
Content-Encoding: gzip
```

**Is this normal?**

Answer (score 6, accepted):

### Yes, that's normal.

If you read the [Apache 2.2 mod_deflate docs](http://httpd.apache.org/docs/2.2/mod/mod_deflate.html), gzip is all over them. That's the compression and decompression scheme that mod_deflate uses (via the `zlib` library).

Answer (score 3):

"gzip" is nothing but [DEFLATE with a CRC-32 checksum and some header / footer info](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Gzip). What you see is just what the module is doing.